# Local package won't compile when remote package recompiles. (Oracle)

Tags: oracle

We have a package on a 10.2.0.4 database(A) and a package on an 11.2.0.2 database(B) that references A's package.  When something on A changes that requires the package on A to do an implicit re-compile, sometimes the package on B that should also implicitly re-compile goes invalid.  The error it shows is PLS-00907:

```
 Cause: PL/SQL is unable to find and load a library unit that was
        previously available.  This typically happens when you try to
        load a unit which references another library unit that is
        non-existent or invalid.
Action: Provide the needed library unit.
```

The strange thing is that the package on A is valid and can be recompiled successfully, yet recompiling the package on B is still unsuccessful.  It is only when we make an inconsequential change to the package on A that the package on B will then compile successfully.  This problem has been occurring every few weeks for the past several months.  It may have started when we upgraded B from 11.1 to 11.2.

The database link on B is a private database link using a specific username/password to connect to A.  The remote_dependencies_mode parameter is set to SIGNATURE on both databases.

This problem is similar, but not the same as MOS [Bug 9719541](https://supporthtml.oracle.com/ep/faces/secure/km/DocumentDisplay.jspx?id=9719541.8&h=Y), and [Doc ID 166680.1](https://supporthtml.oracle.com/ep/faces/secure/km/DocumentDisplay.jspx?id=166680.1&h=Y).  Anyone have any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is obviously a bug, so should go to Oracle support.
As a workaround, are you able to switch that call on the 11gR2 to dynamic SQL to avoid the hard-coded dependency.

You might be able to do that through a wrapper package on the 11g side.
Rather than

```
11g package calls 10g package
```

it goes

```
11g package calls 11g wrapper and 11g wrapper (dynamically) calls 10g package.
```

Comment: I have opened an SR with Oracle, but based on the cases I have opened recently they won't help much since I can't give them a reproducible test case.

Comment: Your workaround would be useful if the problem were more frequent or occurred to a  more critical piece of code.  We may use it if support isn't forthcoming.